# Uninstall Ubuntu without access to uninstall file

Tags: wubi, uninstall

I tried to use the Windows add remove program to uninstall Ubuntu, but it says I dont have access to the uninstall-wubi.  which is apparantly on my H drive which windows doesnt even know exists.  is it possible to download an uninstall-wubi and use it

Comment: Isn't your real problem that you can't access your H drive from Windows? Which doesn't belong here on Askubuntu.

Comment: You can manually uninstall the bits that are left (just registry and boot entry, if you already removed `H:`): https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_do_I_manually_uninstall_Wubi.3F

Answer (score 0):

Try to run Windows in an administrative-modus (Administrator) NOT as a user. 
Try to repeat the nessecary steps for removing Ubuntu out of Windows: via add/remove software, select in the prompted window 'Ubuntu' and click to remove it.

Normaly Windows will ditch Ubuntu from it's system. (It takes for about 3 minutes or so)

If you have special Security software on your system, please check this software wether it allows you to install or remove software (these are all paid versions, so easy to check).